# Select max of absolute value for each numeric column by a grouping column in data.table or dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Here is an example of what my data.frame looks like:

```
opts <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)
df <- data.frame(combo1=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo2=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo3=sample(opts, 6),
                 gene=rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), each=2), stringsAsFactors=F)

df
   combo1 combo2 combo3 gene
1   0.40   0.50  -0.10   g1
2   0.10  -0.20  -0.35   g1
3  -0.35  -0.35   0.40   g2
4   0.00   0.10  -0.30   g2
5  -0.45  -0.10   0.05   g3
6  -0.40  -0.40  -0.05   g3
```

For each combo, I want to group by gene and then select the maximum absolute value. I can accomplish this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df_final <- data.frame(row.names=unique(df$gene))

for (combo in colnames(df)[1:3]) {

    combo_preds <- df[, c(combo, "gene")]
    colnames(combo_preds) <- c("pred", "gene")

    combo_preds %>%
        group_by(gene) %>%
        arrange(desc(abs(pred))) %>%
        slice(1) %>%
        ungroup() ->
        combo_preds

    #add to df_final
    class(combo_preds) <- "data.frame"
    df_final[combo_preds$gene, combo] <- combo_preds$pred
}
#names rows based on gene
row.names(df_final) <- unique(df$gene)

df_final
    combo1 combo2 combo3
g1   0.40   0.50  -0.35
g2  -0.35  -0.35   0.40
g3  -0.45  -0.40   0.05
```

Is there a way that I can accomplish the above with data.table or some other more efficient implementation? In reality, I have ~1300 dfs, each with ~14000 genes and ~650 combos. The current implementation takes 2.6 minutes per df so it will take over 2 days.

Comment: You probably want to use `set.seed` before making a random example data set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly can do it with `data.table`. (I didn't do a benchmark against your version).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function (col) col[which.max(abs(col))]), by='gene']
```

It essentially groups your table by gene, and on each chunk of table uses `lapply` to loop over each column to find the value with the maximum absolute value.

However, I think you might be better off reshaping your table to long format, though I think it depends on your specific data (you'll have to try and see).

```
opts <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)
n.combos <- 600
n.genes <- 10000
n.rows.per.gene <- 5

# columns are called X1 X2 instead of combo1 combo2 but no matter.
df.wide <- data.frame(replicate(n.combos, sample(opts, n.rows.per.gene, replace=T)),
                      gene=rep(paste0("g", 1:n.genes), each=n.rows.per.gene))
```

Here `df.wide` looks like your dataframe, with one column per combo and one row for each replicate for each gene.

Here's the original `data.table` answer:

```
# data.table option
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df.wide)
system.time({
out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function (col) col[which.max(abs(col))]), by='gene']
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  10.757   0.364  12.612
```

Now we reshape to long format, which just has a 'combo' column and a 'value' column:

```
# reshape to long
dt.long <- melt(dt, id.vars='gene', variable.name='combo')
# > head(dt.long)
#    gene combo value
# 1:   g1    X1  0.20
# 2:   g1    X1  0.30
# 3:   g1    X1  0.10
# 4:   g1    X1  0.05
# 5:   g1    X1  0.30
# 6:   g2    X1  0.20

system.time({out.long <- dt.long[, value[which.max(value)], by='gene,combo']})

   user  system elapsed 
  8.000   0.472   9.525
```

This gives you a dataframe with the gene, combo and value that was the maximum absolute. You could reshape it back to wide if you wanted.

So it doesn't seem much faster - I guess you will have to try it on your data and see. I suppose even if the second method is faster, you still have to factor the time taken to cast the datatable to long (which doesn't seem like much).

Compare to e.g. `dplyr` (which is very elegant to use, but slower)

```
system.time({
out.dplyr <- df.wide %>% group_by(gene) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))]))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 163.106   7.989 189.788
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much simpler and faster `dplyr` method:

```
df %>% group_by(gene) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))]))
```

Try it on reproducible data:

```
set.seed(495)
opts <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)
df <- data.frame(combo1=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo2=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo3=sample(opts, 6),
                 gene=rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), each=2), stringsAsFactors=F)

df
```

> ```
>   combo1 combo2 combo3 gene
> 1  -0.15   0.50  -0.25   g1
> 2  -0.45  -0.50   0.15   g1
> 3  -0.25   0.10  -0.30   g2
> 4   0.35  -0.40  -0.15   g2
> 5  -0.05  -0.35  -0.40   g3
> 6   0.15  -0.05  -0.10   g3
> ```

```
df %>% group_by(gene) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))]))
```

> ```
>    gene combo1 combo2 combo3
> 1    g1  -0.45   0.50  -0.25
> 2    g2   0.35  -0.40  -0.30
> 3    g3   0.15  -0.35  -0.40
> ```

Note that in the above case there's a tie in the absolute value for `combo2` and `gene=g1`. If that matters, you'll need to decide how to break ties.

Timings for my `dplyr` method and a slightly faster version of @mathematical.coffee's `data.table` method (using a much larger sample data frame):

```
set.seed(495)
opts <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)
df <- data.frame(combo1=sample(opts, 9e4, replace=TRUE),
                 combo2=sample(opts, 9e4, replace=TRUE),
                 combo3=sample(opts, 9e4, replace=TRUE),
                 gene=rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), each=3e4), stringsAsFactors=F)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr=setDF(df) %>% group_by(gene) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))])),
  data.table={setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function (col) col[which.max(abs(col))]), by='gene']}
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
>      dplyr 10.013623 11.839132 14.156735 12.284574 12.675220 32.35739   100   b
> data.table  4.434841  6.008701  6.947104  6.222775  6.415083 29.52652   100  a
> ```

So the `data.table` version runs in about half the time of the `dplyr` version.

**UPDATE:** To address @Arun's comment, here's a much larger sample data frame with more columns and more `gene` categories.

```
# Large sample of fake data
set.seed(194)
genes=apply(expand.grid(letters,letters), 1, paste, collapse="")
df = data.frame(replicate(50, rnorm(26*26*1e3)), gene=genes)
object.size(df)
# 273 MB

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr=setDF(df) %>% group_by(gene) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))])),
  data.table={setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function (col) col[which.max(abs(col))]), by='gene']},
  times=10
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>      dplyr 1240.1695 1299.0425 1375.8298 1318.5343 1385.5854 1748.8112    10   b
> data.table  464.5597  493.8959  527.7097  519.3607  585.1482  603.3916    10  a
> ```

**UPDATE 2:** Same as above, but with an even larger number of groups (26^3 instead of 26^2). As @Arun discussed, the `data.table` speed advantage increases with the larger number of groups.

```
   # Large sample of fake data
   set.seed(194)
   genes=apply(expand.grid(letters,letters,letters), 1, paste, collapse="")
   df = data.frame(replicate(50, rnorm(26*26*26*50)), gene=genes)
   object.size(df)
   # 356 MB

   microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
     dplyr=setDF(df) %>% group_by(gene) %>%
       summarise_each(funs(.[which.max(abs(.))])),
     data.table={setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function (col) col[which.max(abs(col))]), by='gene']},
     times=1
   )
```

> ```
>    Unit: seconds
>              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>             dplyr 27.567790 27.567790 27.567790 27.567790 27.567790 27.567790     1        
>        data.table  2.765047  2.765047  2.765047  2.765047  2.765047  2.765047     1
> ```

Comment: Your benchmark data size is 2.7MB (fits entirely in cache even), whereas mathematical.coffee's is ~230MB. It's hard to get an idea of how well a tool performs/scales without having reasonably sized data.. I think it is also because his/her data set has a lot of columns. And `dplyr` evaluates each column *separately* (so that you can refer to the previous column directly within), which is fine as long as the function is optimised for hybrid evaluation, but very inefficient otherwise.

Comment: Much nicer code to look at than original approach, but for some reason took about a minute slower (2.62mins vs 3.53mins). In contrast @mathematical.coffee's data.table method clocked in at 42s.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks for following up. Not entirely, but much better. It helps understand the reason for performance difference even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One method in base R that will work (there are many others)

```
# for max absolute value, build a function
maxAbsObs <- function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))]


aggregate(df[,grep("combo", names(df))], list(df$gene), maxAbsObs)
```

---

Here is a `data.table` method to select the maximum absolute value of each combo by gene:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, maxAbsObs), by="gene"]
```

Comment: No this is right, except OP wants max *absolute* value not max value.

Answer (score 0):

@mathematical.coffee 's answer is quite fine with lapply  but there's a more data.table way to achieve the same goal:

```
opts <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)
dt <- data.table(combo1=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo2=sample(opts, 6),
                 combo3=sample(opts, 6),
                 gene=rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), each=2))

dt
```

> ```
>    combo1 combo2 combo3 gene 
> 1:  -0.20  -0.40  -0.10   g1 
> 2:   0.15   0.15   0.40   g1 
> 3:   0.35   0.10  -0.05   g2 
> 4:   0.45  -0.15  -0.25   g2 
> 5:   0.00  -0.25   0.50   g3 
> 6:   0.10   0.20   0.25   g3
> ```

```
dt2 <- dt[, .(combo1=max(combo1), combo2=max(combo2), combo3=max(combo3)), 
            keyby=gene]

dt2
```

> ```
>    gene combo1 combo2 combo3
> 1:   g1   0.15   0.15   0.40
> 2:   g2   0.45   0.10  -0.05
> 3:   g3   0.10   0.20   0.50
> ```

Late but hope this help someone else :(